# What is Mongo cursor's unevaluated state?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

According to the documentation the cursor's `rewind()` method

> rewinds this cursor to its unevaluated state.

Why the term *unevaluated state*? Is some evaluation going on behind the scenes when cursor is first retrieved, or is this only a misleading term for the *initial position*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `cursor` is like an iterator over a MongoDB query result; lazy evaluation. Thus is evaluated and can only be consumed during iteration.

Calling `rewind` set the `Cursor` to its *unevaluated* state, as if it wasn't consumed. But note that new iteration will send a new query to the server and the result might be different.

Comment: Are consuming and evaluating synonyms here?

Comment: It is evaluated when you start consuming the `Cursor`

Answer (score 0):

it's just a cursor, rewind to the initial position.